# How to change ActionBar icons after setTheme()?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm changing application theme with this code:

MainActivity.java:

```
setTheme(R.style.AppBlackTheme);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />
<style name="AppBlackTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />
```

It's working fine, but I have custom icons in ActionBar. And this icons too dark for my black theme. So I need to change this icons to another. How to change ActionBar icons (not app logo) according theme?

Comment: Here is working answer for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14608585/1393280