# How to change the Action bar action icons depending on theme

Tags: android

I have an app where I allow the user to change the theme to change through preferences. I am just changing the from `Theme.Holo` to `Theme.Holo.Light` . Everything works fine, except the action bar action icons.

How do I change the icons depending upon theme? Currently they are hardcoded in `menu.xml` as follows:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:orderInCategory="50"
       app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" 
      android:title="@string/action_search"/>

     <item
    android:id="@+id/action_expandall"
    android:orderInCategory="55"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_expandall"/>

              <item
    android:id="@+id/action_collapseall"
    android:orderInCategory="60"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_collapseall"/>


 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_selecteverything"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_selecteverything"/>

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_selectallcategories"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_selectallcategories"/>


   <item
    android:id="@+id/action_selectallfeeds"
    android:orderInCategory="103"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_selectallfeeds"/>

     <item
    android:id="@+id/action_selectnone"
    android:orderInCategory="104"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_selectnone"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="105"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="107"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/navigation_refresh"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>


        <item
    android:id="@+id/action_accept"
    android:orderInCategory="108"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/navigation_accept"
    android:title="@string/action_accept"/>

          <item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="109"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_logout"/>

            <item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="110"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_about"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One posible solution is to create two different menus.xml holding the light and dark icons and before you inflate the menu, check what the current theme is and choose one or another.

EDIT:

Here @Steven Byle has resolved this in a more beautiful way (which is using themes): https://stackoverflow.com/a/14608585/2025299