# Switch Home action bar icon depending on selected theme

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I spend 3 days looking and serching for solution how to change the `Action bar` `icon` depending on what theme is used in `theme.xml`.

My first attempt how to achieve this was to bring `?attr/`attribute to `AndroidManifest.xml`, but soon I realize this is not possible.

So than I was playing around `style.xml` and `theme.xml` file. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761677/change-actionbar-menu-icons-depending-on-style/14608585#14608585) on SO. This is ok, but the `icon` does not appear...

I want it to appear exactly as when I set `android:logo="@drawable/logo"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`(so in left corner).

My code in theme.xml:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="actionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
    <item name="customSearchIcon">@drawable/logo</item> 
</style>
```

My menu/login.xml file:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:icon="?attr/customSearchIcon"
    android:title="@string/settings"/>
```

EDIT: The problem ->
1) Why this is not working - android:icon="?attr/customSearchIcon" ?
2) How to set the icon exactly in the same position like when you set icon in `AndroidManifest.xml` by `android:logo="@drawable/logo"` (so in left corner).

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: what exactly is your problem? Do you want to set actionbar icon as back button?

Comment: Try moving `<item name="customSearchIcon">@drawable/logo</item>` in the main theme (not the action bar style).

Comment: @miav This make no difference :/

Comment: actionbar icon can be set programmatically but how would you change the theme dynamically?